# increment timestamps by arbitrary deltatime and couple with data list

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop, while-loop, increment

I think there is a simple answer to this, but i just cant get my head around it.
Basically I have a list of data which is the result of

```
span = 2
datas = a['value'].split(",")
Data_list = [".".join(datas[i:i+span]) for i in range(0, len(datas), span)]

#Where a['value'] is a list
```

I'm trying to make a new list coupling the first result from Data_list, with a timestamp. Then the second with `Date_time + deltatime`, the third, `Date_time + 2* deltatime`, etc.

```
#Where T['value'] is a list
Date_time = datetime.strptime(T['value'], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S').time()
deltatime = 9e-5
```

Currently I am using this code

```
#################
DeltaTimeS = 9e-5
#################

Date_time = datetime.strptime(T['value'], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S').time()
print 'Date_time =',Date_time 

def addSecs(tm, secs):
    fulldate = datetime(100, 1, 1, tm.hour, tm.minute, tm.second)
    fulldate = fulldate + timedelta(seconds=secs)
    return fulldate.time()

#a = datetime.now().time()
a = Date_time
b = addSecs(a, DeltaTimeS)

#for a in Data['result'][:1]:      #only print the first result in the list

span = 2
datas = a['value'].split(",")
Data_list = [".".join(datas[i:i+span]) for i in range(0, len(datas), span)]

for a in Data_list:
    print a,b
```

Which prints

```
0.02027 14:59:08.000090
0.01549 14:59:08.000090
0.00559 14:59:08.000090
-0.00760 14:59:08.000090
-0.02439 14:59:08.000090
```

a list with all the data and the time stamp (which only changes once), rather than increasing each time. Any help would be amazing
Maybe counting the size of the first list with "len" and then making that the range for "b" but how do i get b to increase each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: The code that you have provided cannot be used to reproduce the output that you receive.  Therefore, my answer is based on what I understand from your question and a lot of improvisation.

The timestamp that you print each time is `b`, which is evaluated once by calling `addSecs`.  Why do you expect it to have a different value for every iteration of your last `for` loop?

If you want to advance the timestamp, you need to call `addSecs` for every loop iteration and to adjust the second parameter accordingly.  One easy way to achieve this, is to use `enumerate` to obtain a counter of loop iterations, and to multiply `DeltaTimeS` by this counter:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

T = {}
T['value'] = "29-12-2016 14:59:08"
a = {}
a['value'] = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"

DeltaTimeS = 9e-5
Date_time = datetime.strptime(T['value'], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S').time()

def addSecs(tm, secs):
    fulldate = datetime(100, 1, 1, tm.hour, tm.minute, tm.second)
    fulldate = fulldate + timedelta(seconds=secs)
    return fulldate.time()

span = 2
datas = a['value'].split(",")
Data_list = [".".join(datas[i:i+span]) for i in range(0, len(datas), span)]

for i, x in enumerate(Data_list):
    print x, addSecs(Date_time, i * DeltaTimeS)
```

The result is:

```
1.2 14:59:08
3.4 14:59:08.000090
5.6 14:59:08.000180
7.8 14:59:08.000270
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't so much that I was expecting the time to keep changing. More that I couldn't figure out how to do it with the date.time format. I was trying with while loops and count but that wasnt getting me there. Thanksssss for the great new tool - enumerate - !!!

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use `enumerate()`, something like:

```
import datetime as dt

# inputs
values = [
    0.02027,
    0.01549,
    0.00559,
    -0.00760,
    -0.02439,
]    
start_time = dt.datetime.now()

delta_time_seconds = 9e-5
format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'

# build a list of data, timestamp tuples    
list_of_tuples = [(value, (start_time +
                           dt.timedelta(seconds=i*delta_time_seconds)
                           ).strftime(format))
                  for i, value in enumerate(values)]

# show what we got
for data_point in list_of_tuples:
    print(data_point[0], data_point[1])
```